# toLocaleDateString time formatting issue (Firefox vs. Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime, firefox, datetime-format

I'm seeing different results for this date formatting command in Chrome and Firefox:

`new Date(1156550400000).toLocaleDateString('en-us', {weekday: 'long', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', hour12: false, timeZone: 'UTC'})+'z'`

in Firefox, I get this result (this is the desired output format):

`Saturday, Aug 26, 00z"`

in Chrome, I get this result:

`"Saturday, Aug 26, 24z"`

Easy enough to check for the "24" value and replace with "00", but hoping for a built in method...
Is there an option that I'm missing in the toLocaleDateString options for formatting, or an alternate approach to get the desired format?

Comment: Looks like a V8 "issue". This happens in node as well (tested on node v12.7.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that option 'hour12' works differently in Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. May be, using option '[hourCycle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/hourCycle)' instead of 'hour12' is helpful in this case.

```
new Date(1156550400000).toLocaleDateString('en-us', {weekday: 'long', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', hourCycle: "h23", timeZone: 'UTC'})+'z'
```

In Mozilla Firefox (82.0 (64-bit)) this returns `"Saturday, Aug 26, 00z"`. In Google Chrome (Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)) this returns `"Saturday, Aug 26, 00z"`.

Comment: This _should_ work, though I'm not actively working that particular task just now. I can't actually test this at the moment...
Accepting this because it seems a lot more elegant than my original, in-place, work-around.